# Is there a way to extend sOrder.php in shopware 5?

Tags: shopware5

There is a need to write custom logic in sOrder.php(engine/Shopware/Core/sOrder.php).
Is there a way to extend sOrder.php in order to write custom logic in shopware 5?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to customize how to do that. You cant extend the class but you can register on events which are dispatched from within this class

e.g. if you want to customize the sGetOrderNumber function

```
public function sGetOrderNumber()
{
    $number = $this->numberRangeIncrementer->increment('invoice');
    $number = $this->eventManager->filter(
        'Shopware_Modules_Order_GetOrdernumber_FilterOrdernumber',
        $number,
        ['subject' => $this]
    );

    return (string) $number;
}
```

Shopware Event

Shopware_Modules_Order_GetOrdernumber_FilterOrdernumber

```
$number = $this->eventManager->filter(
        'Shopware_Modules_Order_GetOrdernumber_FilterOrdernumber',
        $number,
        ['subject' => $this]
    );
```

You would register to this event to modify the number result created within the function.

Or you can hook the whole function (in case it is declared as public) with before, after or replace hooks, which mean to execute your code before, after or instead of the original function.

e.g. sOrder::sGetOrderNumber::replace to do sth. completely different or sOrder::sGetOrderNumber::after to do sth. after this function got called.

Comment: Hi,
I want to extend getPartnerCode(), Which is private (sOrder.php). Is there any Way to add custom code/extend  this private function?

Comment: unfortunately not cause its private, but there is only one spot where this result is used and there you can register on the event Shopware_Modules_Order_SaveOrder_FilterParams which provides all the data which is going to be saved and you can modify it. $args->getReturn()['partnerID']

Answer (score 0):

From most advised to least advised, you can do the following things to extend the current functionality:

1. [Hook on events](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/event-guide/)
2. Decorate using [Service Extensions](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/shopware-5-core-service-extensions/)
3. Write your own git diff patch and apply using Composer in the [Scripts tag](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)